# Webpack with typescript not finding entry module

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I am attempting to integrate webpack into my typescript application.  In order to learn webpack I attempted a minimal migration.  So I cloned the Angular2 [quickstart seed](https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git), added a webpack.config.js:

```
'use strict';
let path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './app/main.ts',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: '/bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
};
```

And attempted a build:

```
PS C:\Users\ltheisen\git\pastdev-test-webpack> .\node_modules\.bin\webpack --display-error-details
Hash: 954fdea72e6d10e35648
Version: webpack 1.14.0
Time: 31ms

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./app/main.ts in C:\Users\ltheisen\git\pastdev-test-webpack
resolve file
  C:\Users\ltheisen\git\pastdev-test-webpack\app\main.ts.tsx doesn't exist
  C:\Users\ltheisen\git\pastdev-test-webpack\app\main.ts.ts doesn't exist
  C:\Users\ltheisen\git\pastdev-test-webpack\app\main.ts.js doesn't exist
resolve directory
  C:\Users\ltheisen\git\pastdev-test-webpack\app\main.ts\package.json doesn't exist (directory description file)
  C:\Users\ltheisen\git\pastdev-test-webpack\app\main.ts is not a directory (directory default file)
```

From the `--display-error-details` output, I can see that it check the file with all 3 extensions from `resolve.extensions`, but not for the file itself.  All of the examples I have found use the file with the extension for `entry` ([webpack basic setup](https://webpack.js.org/guides/webpack-and-typescript/#basic-setup), [typescript integrating with build tools](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html), ...).  If I remove the extension, the webpack build finds the `entry` file (though I seem to have other problems...).

Anyway, my question is this: am I doing something wrong?  Missing something obvious?  Or is the documentation wrong?

**---- UPDATE ----**
It appears it may be something wrong with the npmjs repository.  Specifically, the [webpack 2 documentation for installation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation/) says:

```
npm install webpack --save-dev
```

However, npmjs shows shows version 1.14.0 as the current version:

[image]

This seems odd because version 2.2.0 was released last week...  But i guess the release hasn't yet propagated to npmjs?  After updating to webpack 2, this seems to have resolved my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack 2 has been at pre-release stage until this moment. I cannot say why 2.2.0 isn't tagged accordingly if it is considered unstable, but it was published this way, `npm dist-tag ls webpack` outputs:

> beta: 2.2.0
>
> latest: 1.14.0

Use appropriate semver to install it:

```
npm install webpack@2 --save-dev
```

Comment: thanks for the info.  I just decided to switch to webpack, so had no idea it was just released.  Just saw that there was a version 2 and that the documentation said to simply use `npm install webpack`.  I naturally assumed it was going to install version 2...  I have since learned better.

Answer (score 1):

npm shows last published version, use `npm view webpack` to find all versions.